# How to create separate file ( .vb or .cs ) for each table in db using subsonic 3.0

Tags: .net, orm, subsonic, subsonic3, data-access-layer

i am using subsonic v.3 to generate my DAL layer in my ASP.NET application with VB.NET(.NET framework 3.5).
i have used the subsonic v.2 and i which it was creating a separate .cs file for each table and event each class file has on method called LoadByParam() or LoadByKey() in case if one want to load the object by passing some field value.

but in subsonic 3 when i add core file and add T4 template in my project it's generating three vb file named activrecord.vb , context.vb and struct.vb

I want to know how can i load all the table in separate file as in subsonic 
how to load a database object by passing some field as a filed 
i.e in subsonic 2.0 when i want to load user table with some give id i was loading it this way
new myProject.user(column-name, filed-value);
how can i achieve the same with subsonic 3.0  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask me, I would add a c# class library to your project and use for your DAL, since the c# have a broader userbase and are thus more tested. VB and C# work perfectly together in a Solution

This said, the latest c# templates already create seperate files: https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/tree/master/ActiveRecord

I suppose nobody migrated the code to vb.net atm.

Regarding your second question (how to load an object by columnname), subsonic 3 makes heavy use of lambda expressions, so you only need to use the overload that takes an Expression(of Func(of User, Boolean))

In other words:

```
dim user1 as new User(Function(x) x.UserName = "Test")
```

or

```
dim user2 as User = User.SingleOrDefault(Function(x) x.UserName = "Test")
```

or even

```
dim user3 as User = (From u in User.All()
                     Where u.UserName = "Test"
                     Select u).SingleOrDefault()
```

the last two return a User object or Nothing.
The first always returns an object, even if the user does not exist, so you have to check
user1.IsNew() if needed.

Comment: thnx SchlaWiener this is exactly what i am looking for, now i will try using new **lambda** expression and try to us C# DAL library since it has separately generated file for each object in my database . thnx

Comment: btw. I find c# more suitable for linq/lambda. `var u = new User(x => x.UserName == "Test")` looks far more readable and the var keyword is nice since `dim u = new User()` makes u an object instead of a user object. So you always have to specify the type at declaration which can result in very long declarations in a linq context.